# RSS feeds to Email, on the fly

Tags: rss, email, atom-feed, feedburner

I have a web app that generates RSS feeds. I would like to offer users the ability to subscribe to these RSS feeds by email.

I know I can use Feedburner to manually burn my feeds and offer email subscriptions. The problem is I offer hundreds of RSS feeds and don’t want to manually burn a feed just for this one feature.

Does anyone know of a service or API (preferably free) that allows you to create an RSS feed to email sign up on the fly? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

-Ace

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Feedburner Managment API](http://code.google.com/apis/feedburner/api_reference.html#Add_Feed) to programatically burn your feeds - and then enable email subscription.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Do you know of any other alternatives? Thanks again

Comment: Truthfully Feedburner has kind of crushed the market. The only other service I'm aware of is http://www.feedmyinbox.com/webmasters/ but there is a open source app you can download and use: http://rss2email.infogami.com/

Comment: Feedburner API is now deprecated... do you know something about it? I want to burn feeds programmatically. Thanks!